# Gulp, merge handlebars templates with other source files?

Tags: javascript, gulp, handlebars.js

I wan't to merge (concatenate) Handlebars, Libraries (jQuery and what have you) and custom javascript into one single js file. But it seems a handlebars task will convert any source to compiled 'handlebars' code. I've been looking at listening for the end event, and then manually go to all the different source locations, but that'll be a mess.

How can I merge all these kinds of files from various destinations into one single file, without manually merging files after run tasks (leaving output all over the place). Passing multiple source paths to a handlebars task is obviously a no go?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge two gulp streams using [merge-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream)

```
var merge      = require('merge-stream');
var gulp       = require('gulp');
var concat     = require('gulp-concat');
var handlebars = require('gulp-handlebars');

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  var hbsStream = gulp.src('templates/*.hbs').pipe(handlebars());
  var jsStream  = gulp.src('scripts/*.js');
  return merge(hbsStream, jsStream).pipe(concat('scripts.js'));
});
```